# Kali linux veil-evasion installation problem

Tags: kali-linux

Does anyone know the cause or fix to this problem?

```
 root@kali:~# cd Veil-Evasion
 root@kali:~/Veil-Evasion# cd setup
 root@kali:~/Veil-Evasion/setup# ./setup.sh

 Veil-Evasion (Setup Script) | [Updated]: 2016-02-23

 [Web]: https://www.veil-framework.com/ | [Twitter]: @VeilFramework


 [I] Kali Linux "2016.1" x86_64 Detected...


 [?] Are you sure you wish to install Veil-Evasion?

 Continue With Installation? ([y]es/[s]ilent/[N]o): y


 [*] Initializing Package Installation

 [*] Adding x86 Architecture To x86_64 System for Wine
 [*] Installing Wine 32bit and 64bit Binaries
 E: Package 'wine32' has no installation candidate
 [ERROR] Failed to install Wine... Exit Code: 100.
```

Comment: This appears to be an issue with Veil. Please refer to their documentation and issues tracker on GitHub.

Comment: I have one other question what is the correct format to put code in on this website?

Comment: In the editor, you will see the `{ }` braces. You can use this, or manually use ` ` ` (the backtick) for in-line code snippets.

Answer (score 1):

A little google goes a long way.

https://github.com/veil-framework/veil-evasion/issues/221

Also you are trying to install the 32bit wine on a 64bit system.

Comment: This is abit different from the problem im having and the error im getting. Is it not?

Comment: It doesn't give me the option to choose

Comment: not at all. You are using the wrong repos and therefore the install script cant find the correct version.

Comment: Sorry for the delay how do i go about changing my repos?

Comment: That is really outside the scope of this forum I would suggest that you read up on Linux administration.